# How to add thumbnail to youtube video upon insert

Tags: php, video, youtube, google-api-php-client, symfony

### Question:

How to correctly add a thumbnail to a youtube video upon insert?

### What I've tried (step-by-step):

In the google-api-php-client exists a service called

```
$snippet = new \Google_Service_YouTube_VideoSnippet();
```

Through this I can set the Thumbnail like so:

```
$snippet->setThumbnails($thumbnail_details);
```

However it asks for a parameter of instance type:

```
$thumbnail_details = new \Google_Service_YouTube_ThumbnailDetails();
```

I figured this was the class where I could set the thumbnail URL, however it wasn't the case. This class has a method called "setDefault" where I can put in parameter another instance of type:

```
$thumbnail_service = new \Google_Service_YouTube_Thumbnail();
```

Which has a method called:

```
$thumbnail_service->setUrl($thumbnail_url);
```

Which is what I have done. The url works fine (ex: [here](http://www.websurg.com/MEDIA/vd01/4682/4682.jpg?1454424695)). Even after setting the url and uploading the video, the wrong thumbnail is set. (I suppose that if there is no thumbnail, it chooses a random frame in the video as a thumbnail)

### Relevant Code:

```
    $thumbnail_service = new \Google_Service_YouTube_Thumbnail();
    $thumbnail_details = new \Google_Service_YouTube_ThumbnailDetails();

    $thumbnail_service->setUrl($thumbnail_url);
    $thumbnail_details->setDefault($thumbnail_service);

    $snippet = new \Google_Service_YouTube_VideoSnippet();
    /*
      Other video info added to snippet
    */
    $snippet->setThumbnails($thumbnail_details);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to find how to upload a thumbnail while uploading the youtube video. After each upload video, I would take the youtube video id from the response returned after uploading, and prepare a second request to upload the thumbnail to that specific video.

```
private function UploadThumbnail($video_id, $url){

    $this->client->setDefer(true);
    $thumb = $this->youtube->thumbnails->set($video_id);
    $media = new \Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
        $this->client,
        $thumb,
        'image/png',
        null,
        true,
        $this->chunkSizeBytes
    );

    $filesize = DataRetrievalService::remote_filesize($url);

    $this->MediaUpload($media, $url, $filesize);
}
private function MediaUpload($media, $path, $filesize = null){
    if(is_null($filesize)){
        $filesize = filesize($path);
    }
    $media->setFileSize($filesize);

    $status = false;
    $handle = fopen($path, "rb");

    while(!$status && !feof($handle)){
        $chunk = fread($handle, $this->chunkSizeBytes);

        $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
    }
    fclose($handle);
    $this->client->setDefer(false);
    return $status;
}
```

If any specific questions about the code I wrote, leave a comment. I'll explain in detail.

Answer (score 1):

use this code to resolve the problem

```
$video_id=$v->getId();
$url="image.jpg";
    $client->setDefer(true);
    $thumb = $youtube->thumbnails->set($video_id);
    $media = new \Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
        $client,
        $thumb,
        'image/png',
        null,
        true,
        $chunkSizeBytes
    );

    $media->setFileSize(filesize($url));
    // Read the media file and upload it chunk by chunk.
    $status = false;
    $handle = fopen($url, "rb");
    while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
      $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
      $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
    }

    fclose($handle);

    // If you want to make other calls after the file upload, set setDefer back to false
    $client->setDefer(false);
```